# What version of C# is used by Mono 2.6.4?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

Perhaps (hopefully) I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see from the Mono site what version of C# is used for any particular version of Mono, and as a C# newbie I'm not sure how to find out directly myself.

My specific question is: what version of C# is used by Mono 2.6.4? (The reason I'm interested in that version is that it seems to be the base version of the Mono variant used by the current version of Unity 3D.)

Comment: Note for Unity, not everything is really there. For example, it doesn't support covariance/contravariance. Particularly, their iPhone support is also limited. Last I checked (and maybe this has changed) it doesn't fully support generics and/or overriding of generic methods due to iOS runtime limitations.

Comment: Mono 2.6.4 supports MOST of the C# 4.0 syntax.  Mono does not support WPF at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6.4#C.23_Language) have this to say:

> If Mono 2.6.1 is configured with the preview mode, you will also get early access to Mono's C# 4.0 implementation. This implementation is now available as part of the dmcs command.
>
> C# 4.0 named arguments and optional parameters have been fully implemented.

So, to be safe, keep to C# 3.0 features.

Comment: Thanks. This goes some way to explaining why there are references to a C# 3.5 around. Is it correct that while there is only officially 3.0 and 4.0 (from Microsoft), Mono has its own C# compiler which implements some 4.0 features on top of base 3.0 support, thus "3.5", which is just a shorthand quasi-version, not a real version of C#?

Comment: @Ghopper21 - There are versions of C# the language which are different from the versions of the .NET framework. See this page by Jon Skeet for illumination: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/versions.aspx

Comment: @Ghopper21 - C# 4.5 has been released.  There is also C# 2.0 and C# 1.0/1.1 the compiler that C# 3.5 is the same as C# 2.0 and 3.0 basically everything you said is incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound - You are also confusing the framework (3.5) with the C# _language_ version. There is no C# 4.5, 3.5 or 1.1. There were _.NET framwork_ versions with those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to use 4.0 by the looks of [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6.4)